# Closing a hole after adding solidify modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I modeled this part of a lightbulb and in order to create some thickness I added a solidify modifier (after adding a sub surf modifier).

[image]

Now i want to "close" this hole of the object.

[image]

But when I do this I don't get a smooth transition between the "old" geometry and the "new" geometry. Why is this ?

[image]

What should I do to "close this hole" and have a nice smooth surface (in combination with the solidify modifier) ? Or should I forget the modifier and created thickness by modelling without modifier ?

After adding some extra loops this is the result. It looks better but it is still like two separate objects are brought together and I wanted to see one object with a smooth transition

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the mesh has a hole with **Solidify** mod this means it has it also without modifier. It's worth revising the model for any holes / doubles etc.

Comment: Its really hard to tell what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post screenshots of your mesh without modifiers? It's hard to tell from the images, but it looks like you have a non-manifold mesh, that is a mesh that could not exist or be built in real life.

In your case it seems you have edges that belong to more than two faces. Specifically that large circular "lid" that makes inner part of the lamp is probably attached to the outer faces causing an inconsistency in your mesh that the solidify modifier can't handle correctly.

I would advise choosing one of the two methods and sticking with it.

If you require modeling the inside of the mesh than abandon the modifiers completely and model it all the way through.

I always prefer a modifiers non destructive workflow so in your case you could either detach the "lid" into a separate object that doesn't use a solidify modifier, or leave it in the same mesh but detach it from the surrounding geometry, making it a separate chunk.

**Edit:** As I mentioned previously, closing the mesh at the selected loop will yield a non manifold mesh, you would be creating a an inner face that would be connected to the outer part of the shell.
I mean, you can do it, but it will generate a mesh that will most likely cause problems with most modifiers and create a topology that is troublesome.

The way I see it you have four choices:

1. Apply the solidify, enter edit mode select the inner center vertex, grow the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> until the desired loops are selected and <kbd>X</kbd> > dissolve faces.
2. Drop the solidify modifier or and manually model the interior with the closed loop as desired. There is an edit mode *Solidify* operator you can use.
3. Leave the solidfy modifier, duplicate the selected loop with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then press <kbd>F</kbd> to close it. It will create a separate chunk of mesh and a discontinuity in the object, but it will remain a manifold watertight object and leave the modifier in place.
4. My favorite would be to rethink the whole object and use a screw modifier instead. Just draw the section of the light bulb and then use a *Screw Modifier*.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I should have uploaded the blend file. I did now (without closing "the hole")

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it, model looks smooth and error free to me, only hole I see is the top opening where the glass will be. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no I don't mean that top opening, but the opening in the narrower part of the object (where I did draw the arrows). Maybe the word "hole" is wrong. I tried to make it clear with the arrows I did draw in the images above. I want to close that "hole". In the blend file the opening is still there. what can I do to explain it better ? The last image is made after closing the "hole", but I did not save the blend file like that

Comment: Yes, I saw your arrow, but I've been looking and looking at your model and I see no "holes" it all seems well modeled and continuous, no errors or discontinuities. The mesh looks smooth, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am terribly sorry that I explain myself so bad. what I mean is ... If you have a top view you can look into the object till the very bottom. What I want is to "close" the object where I painted the arrows (because I think that is also closed in a real lightbulb - but maybe I am wrong). Sorry for your time

Comment: I now re-uploaded the blend file and I made the solidify modifier inactive and selected the loop in the mesh where i want to close the mesh. Is this more clear ? If I close the mesh there and make the solidify modifier active then I get the result like in the last image

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean now, I'll update my answer later, right now I can't look into it any further

Comment: A couple of things to try: -Move the subsurf modifier below the solidify modifier. -Change the solidify "Offset" to Zero. - Add an edge loop or two.

Comment: @Dontwalk I tried your suggestions. adding an edge loop or two improved the result but there is still a crease between the "old"mesh and the added geometry. But perhaps that is normal ?

Comment: Updated original answer to reflect provided details. As mentioned you have to stick with a method that suits your model, or settle with a non manifold mesh